# iPodMusicPlayer stops when app comes to foreground

Tags: iphone, ios, multitasking, mpmusicplayercontroller

I hava an aiPhone application which play the iPhone library music. i am currently using the iPodMusicPlayer. When the application goes to the background every thing is still working fine. But when it comes to the foreground the iPodMusicPlayer stops. Is there any solution to this problem or should i use the AVPlayer.Thanks

Comment: this is the first thing i did. The problem is when my applications comes back to the foreground the iPodeMusicPlayer stops playing.Some posts say that you should save your state when applications will resign active and some others say that you should use the AVPlayer.I am a little bit confused here